# Webpack output type "var" in production

Tags: webpack

In webpack 5, when the output of webpack configuration is specified as

```
output: {
           
            filename: mode === "bundle.js",
            path: "./dist/",
            library: {
                name: "mylib",
                type: "var"
            }
        }
```

The bundle file generated has the variable named `mylib` as expected for dev. However, in production, the output variable name `mylib` is minified as a random letter. I know for production it minified the code by default, that's not a problem. But why is this output name also minified? How do apps use `mylib` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had

```
experiments: {
  outputModule: true
}
```

in my webpack configuration. Removing it and then the "mylib" is not minified.